# Getting lemon parser conflict

Tags: c, parsing, lemon

I am trying to write a simple parser using lemon, for a javascript-like language. I am unable to resolve a conflict error, and I suspect it is a unsolvable problem.

The conflict is between the grammar for:

```
{x = 10;}
```

and

```
{x:10};
```

The first is a statement block containing an assignment statement and the second is an expression statement defining an object.

A grammar to parse both of them results in a conflict. The minimal code is as follows:

```
rMod ::= rStmt.

rStmt ::= rStmtList RCURLY. {leaveScope();}
rStmtList ::= rStmtList rStmt.
rStmtList ::= LCURLY. {enterScope();}

rStmt ::= rExpr SEMI.

rExpr ::= rObj.
rObj ::= LCURLY rObjItemList RCURLY.
rObjItemList ::= rObjItemList COMMA rObjItem.
rObjItemList ::= rObjItem.
rObjItem ::= ID COLON rExpr.

rExpr ::= ID.
rExpr ::= NUM.
```

The out file shows the following:

```
State 4:
  (3) rStmtList ::= LCURLY *
      rObj ::= LCURLY * rObjItemList RCURLY
      rObjItemList ::= * rObjItemList COMMA rObjItem
      rObjItemList ::= * rObjItem
      rObjItem ::= * ID COLON rExpr

                        ID shift        8      
                        ID reduce       3       ** Parsing conflict **
              rObjItemList shift        6      
                  rObjItem shift-reduce 8      rObjItemList ::= rObjItem
                 {default} reduce       3      rStmtList ::= LCURLY
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this would be gratefully accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heart of the problem is that you want to execute `enterScope()` after the brace which initiates a statement block. However, if the brace is followed by the two tokens `VAR` and `:`, then it starts an object literal, not a block. So it is impossible to know whether or not to execute the `enterScope` action without two-token lookahead, and lemon does not produce LR(2) grammars. To that extent, you are correct that the problem is unsolvable. But of course there are solutions.

Probably the worst solution from any perspective (readability, complexity, verificability) is to create an LR(1) grammar using the usual LR(2)→LR(1) transformation, which will allow you to call the `enterScope();` action at the point where it is clear that a scope has been entered. This means delaying the reduction by one token. That in turn means dividing `expr` into two disjoint non-terminals: those `expr` which can start with a `VAR` and those which cannot. For those `expr` which can start with a `VAR`, you also need to provide a mechanism which essentially allows you to glue together a `VAR` and the rest of the `expr`; in the case of expressions, that is particularly ugly (but still possible). The goal is to be able to write:

```
block(A)       ::= blockPrefix(B) RCURLY .                 { closeScope(); A = B;} 
blockPrefix(A) ::= lcurlyOpen exprNotStartingVAR(E) .      { A = E; }
blockPrefix(A) ::= lcurlyVAR(V) restOfExprStartingVar(R) . { A = makeExpr(V, R); }
blockPrefix(A) ::= blockPrefix(B) SEMI expr(E) .           { A = appendExpr(B, E); }
lcurlyOpen     ::= LCURLY .                                { openScope(); }
lcurlyVAR(A)   ::= LCURLY VAR(V) .                         { openScope(); A = V; }
```

An alternative, which is also ugly but probably less ugly in this particular case, is to recognize a variable name followed by a colon as a single lexical token (`VAR_COLON`). Although that complicates the lexer (particularly since you need to recognize constructs where whitespace or even comments appear between the variable name and the colon), it makes the grammar much simpler. With that change, there is no conflict because the object literal must start with a `VAR_COLON` while an expr can only start with a `VAR` (or other unrelated tokens).

A much simpler solution is to not try to create the *scope* [inherited attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_grammar#Inherited_attributes). If we do scope resolution synthetically, then the problem more or less vanishes:

```
stmt       ::= expr SEMI | block .
stmtList   ::= stmt .
stmtList   ::= stmtList stmt .
block(A)   ::= LCURLY stmtList(B) RCURLY . { A = applyScope(newScope(), B); }
objLiteral ::= LCURLY itemList RCURLY .
objLiteral ::= LCURLY RCURLY .
itemList   ::= item .
itemList   ::= itemList COMMA item .
item       ::= VAR COLON expr .
expr       ::= VAR .
expr       ::= objLiteral .
...
```

That grammar has no conflicts, but it might radically change the way you handle scopes, since it requires variable names to be scoped once a block is complete rather than doing it in-line as the parse proceeds.

However, I would argue that for most languages (including Javascript), it is actually more convenient to do scoping at the end of a block, or even as a post-parse walk over the AST. Javascript, unlike C, allows local variables to be declared after their first mention. Local functions can even be used before their declaration. (This is subtly different from Python, where a function declaration is an executable assignment, but the scoping rules are similar.)

As another example, C++ allows class members to be declared anywhere inside the declaration of the class, even if the member has already been mentioned inside another class member function.

And there are many other examples. These scoping rules generally benefit the programmer by allowing stylistic options (such as putting member variable definitions at the end of a class definition in C++) which would not be possible in C.

Comment: Brilliant.. thanks. I'll probably go with the 3rd option. post-parse traversal of the AST.

Comment: What version of lemon do you use? My lemon doesn't support rules with `|`

Comment: @kravemir: quite right, thanks. I fixed it. The previous one was imperfectly converted from bison format.

Comment: And, what about `$$`? :-)

Comment: @kravemir: Most of the actions were irrelevant, so I just removed them, but I think I fixed the ones which remain.